# Los fragment se crean con un fondo Gris y no blanco como por defecto

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

En mi proyecto cuando creo un fragment los crea y los fondos en vez de ser Blanco o Transparente lo crea con un color gris, el cual a la hora de ejecutar cualquier componente de tipo gridLayout por ejemplo muestra en los bordes un color gris, obviamente por eso, de todas formas, estoy segundo de que si soluciono lo del fondo gris, todo se me solucionará (es visual solamente)[image: Esto es com ose ve los fragments al crearlos o cualquier componente nuevo y quiero que vuelva a ser blanco como siempre a sido en cualquier proyecto.]

Añado un Fragment nuevo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es el layout que usas, agregalo por favor. si cambia a color gris definitivamente en alguna parte se esta agregando ese backgroun.

Comment: Amigo, eso es el item que uso en un gridLayout, pero es que me sale en todo, es decir al crear cualquier Xml (fragment) me los crea asi con ese fondo gris. Mira, voy a crear un Fragment nuevo sin añadir nada.

Comment: Cuando ejecutas tu aplicación en verdad se ven con color gris?

Comment: Si. Si pruebas tu en crear un fragment, por defecto el fragment es Blanco, al cotrario que el mio ahora me los lanza gris.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones, definir el color blanco como background dentro del layout:

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

o programaticamente cambiar el color:

```
fragment.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```